# Is there an Android app to share data with an HTTP/HTTPS POST?

Tags: android, sharing

(migrated from https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219184)

I'm trying to send an audio recording from my Android to my website using the share menu.

Ideally, I'd like an app that I can configure with a URL and that appears in the share menu. When I select the app's share icon, it sends the data to the preconfigured URL in a POST operation.

Note: My question isn't how to code it, as I'm pretty sure that I can do that. I'm asking if such an app already exists, as I just can't believe that somebody hasn't already written an app to do this!